# nHibernate queryover subquery on many-to-many

Tags: nhibernate, subquery, queryover

I have three tables in my database

1. Appointment (Id, BunchOfFields)
2. AppointmentAttendee (AppointmentId,ContactId)
3. Contact (Id, ContactFields)

An appointment can have 1 or more Attendee which is just a contact. I have these mapped:

```
<class name="Appointment">
    <set name ="Attendees" table="AppointmentAttendee">
      <key column="AppointmentId"></key>
      <many-to-many class="Cutter.Domain.Contact" column="ContactId"/>

    </set>
</class>
```

I need to get all the appointments (with all attendees), which have a specific contact, and which starts inside a specific timeframe. So far I have:

```
        CurrentSession.QueryOver<Appointment>()
            .Where(a=>a.StartDate>=start && a.StartDate<=end)
```

What I need is basically this SQL Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Appointment a
LEFT JOIN OtherTables....
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM AppointmentAttendee att WHERE a.Id=att.AppointmentId and att.ContactId=?)
```

**EDIT**
So far I have come up with this:

```
   var list=CurrentSession.QueryOver<Appointment>(() => appt)
                    .JoinAlias(()=>appt.Work, ()=>work)
                    .Where(a => (a.StartDate >= start && a.StartDate <= end) 
                     &&   work.Status==WorkStatus.Active )
                                           .JoinQueryOver<Contact>(a => a.Attendees)
                    .Where(u => u.Id == assignedTo)

                    .List<Appointment>();
```

But I believe this is joining the appointments with the attendees, and will limit the attendees that I get back.

**EDIT**
Some more experimenting lead me to this. (Note some of the objects changed from Contact to User but still same problem)

```
        Appointment appt=null;
        WorkBase work=null;

        var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<Appointment>()
            .JoinQueryOver<User>(a => a.InternalAttendees)             
            .Where(u => u.Id == assignedTo)
            .SelectList(a => a.Select(c=>c.Id));

        var list=CurrentSession.QueryOver<Appointment>(() => appt)
            .JoinAlias(()=>appt.Work, ()=>work)
            .Where(a => (a.StartDate >= start && a.StartDate <= end)
                && work.Status==WorkStatus.Active )            
            .WithSubquery.WhereExists(subQuery)              
            .List<Appointment>();
```

Now I am getting the subquery, but how do I connect the subquery to the parentquery. (Need subquery to reference the outer appointment id)

Also it would be nice if I could do this without having to join the entity tables in the subquery seems wrong to have to join three tables when all the data I need is in the association table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a clause in your sub query referring to your alias (Where(a => a.Id == appt.Id)):

```
    Appointment appt=null;
    WorkBase work=null;

    var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<Appointment>()
        .Where(a => a.Id == appt.Id) // restrict it to Appointment in outer query
        .JoinQueryOver<User>(a => a.InternalAttendees)             
        .Where(u => u.Id == assignedTo)             
        .SelectList(a => a.Select(c=>c.Id));

    var list=CurrentSession.QueryOver<Appointment>(() => appt)
        .JoinAlias(()=>appt.Work, ()=>work)
        .Where(a => (a.StartDate >= start && a.StartDate <= end)
            && work.Status==WorkStatus.Active )            
        .WithSubquery.WhereExists(subQuery)              
        .List<Appointment>();
```

Comment: you know if there is a way to force nhibernate to do the subquery without joining the other two tables?

Comment: With your mapping as is you can do it in a very ugly manner using Restrictions.Sql, you could also do it using hql (but then you lose the power of Criteria/QueryOver), alternatively you could achieve it by mapping the AppointmentAttendee table to a class (using a composite key), but all of those options are a fair amount of effort - depends how important it is to you

Comment: Not worth it until I need to optimize the system, this is a small portion of a much larger query which is getting rather large as it is...thanks for the advice!